# IIS 8.5 Serve file with no extension from particular folder

Tags: iis-8.5, static-files

I have some files that have been uploaded to a folder called `/Download` however the have no extension e.g. `File1` I have tried adding a `/Download/Web.Config` file with the following specified

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".*" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But with this in place I still receive this error from IIS:

> HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found The requested content appears to be
> script and will not be served by the static file handler.
>
> Most likely causes:
> The request matched a wildcard mime map. The request is mapped to the
> static file handler. If there were different pre-conditions, the
> request will map to a different handler.
>
> Things you can try: If you want to serve this content as a static
> file, add an explicit MIME map.

Comment: Have you tried with just a dot?

`<mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="application/octet-stream" />`

Comment: I tried with jusr a * but not with just a dot... Ill test now!

Comment: Yeah that worked - I knew it would be something silly - if you add that as an answer Ill mark it correct!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Looking forward to the points :-)

Comment: The points are yours my friend!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried with just a dot?

`<mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="application/octet-stream" />`